# Mysql simple stored procedure syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I write a simple mysql stored procedure in workbench, however, it complains syntax error. What is wrong with my syntax?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SelectIndicatorsByExistReferenceID`()
BEGIN
    select * from indicators;       
END
```

Comment: If you're getting an error, please add it to you question. This will help us finding the error faster

Answer (score 0):

You'd better post your error messages, even though I can guess the problem you are suffering.

The default delimiter of MySQL is ";". So MySQL Workbench treat the statement below as a complete statement:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SelectIndicatorsByExistReferenceID`()
BEGIN
    select * from indicators;
```

It's definitely wrong!

So you should **change the delimiter expilictly** when you write procedures. Here is an example:

```
delimiter //  -- change the delimiter temporarily
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SelectIndicatorsByExistReferenceID`()
BEGIN
    select * from indicators;       
END //
delimiter ;   -- restore the default delimiter
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) for a simple example of a Stored Procedure.
To your question: When you define a SP, you always start with setting a new delimiter in order to use the normal delimiter (`;`) in your SP. If you don't do this, SQL thinks that you finished your query after the smicolon, which isn't at the end of your query so it throws an error. To set a new delimiter, do the following:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SelectIndicatorsByExistReferenceID`()
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM indicators;
   ...
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

So now, you first set the delimiter to `//` and sql just stores the simicolons in your SP. At the `END`, you say that your query is done and type `//` - the new delimiter. Then you set it back to the normal simicolon in order to continue as always.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`locahost` PROCEDURE `SelectIndicatorsByExistReferenceID`()
BEGIN

SELECT * from indicators;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`locahost` PROCEDURE `SelectIndicatorsByExistReferenceID`()
BEGIN

SELECT * from indicators;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```